# How do I convert text to hyperlink in a WPF RichTextBox FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, hyperlink, flowdocument

I'm trying to turn some text to Hyperlink while a user is typing in WPF RichTextBox.

My first attempt at it involves running this code at each KeyUp:

```
Regex r = new Regex("[A-Z]{3}");
FlowDocument doc = this.inputBox.Document;            
String text = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd).Text;

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(text))
{
    TextPointer start = doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + 2);                
    TextPointer end = doc.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(m.Index + m.Length + 2);
    Hyperlink sp = new Hyperlink(start, end);
}
```

This runs correctly the first time a user enters a sequence of 3 capital letters, ABC, but hyperlink creation fails with an exception when a second sequence is entered. Looking at the variable while debugging, it appears that the two TextPointers keep pointing at the first sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be due to a common misunderstanding of what the GetPositionAtOffset() method does.

GetPositionAtOffset returns the offset *within the FlowDocument markup*, not the *visible text character offset*.

After you insert your first hyperlink, the FlowDocument contains opening and closing tags:

```
<Hyperlink>the_regex_match</Hyperlink>
```

This means that the FlowDocument offsets no longer align with the plain text character indexes returned by the RegEx match.